# Table function giving me long tabulations instead of wide in r (needed for chi-square analysis)

Tags: r, chi-squared

I'm struggling to get my dataset to work with the table function in r. I have two unique columns as factors that I am trying to tabulate into one column for student ethnicity and nine columns for the ethnicity that they drew. I can manually make this work, but I want a contingency table to work through chi-squared analysis with. I've tried everything I can think of and cannot make this work.

**Whenever I have used the table function, it looks like this:**

```
Predict_Table <- table(Student_Ethnicity, PreDAS_Ethnicity)
```

[image: Wrong Table]

**I want my data to look like this (but obviously with more columns - and it has to be able to work with a chi-squared analysis)**:
[image: Correct Image]

**My Dataset (Predict_DAS)**:

```
structure(list(Student_Ethnicity = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 
5L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 
4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 
5L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 5L, 1L, 
5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 
9L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 
3L, 9L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
8L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
7L, 2L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("White/Caucasian", 
"Other", "Multiple", "Black/African American", "Hispanic/Latinx", 
"American Indian or Alaskan Native", "No Selection", "Native Hawaiian or Pacific Islander", 
"Asian"), class = "factor"), PreDAS_Ethnicity = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 
9L, 2L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 1L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
5L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 
4L, 7L, 1L, 7L, 4L, 7L, 1L, 9L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 1L, 7L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 4L, 9L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 7L, 9L, 7L, 1L, 
4L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 7L, 4L, 7L, 
2L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 
7L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 4L, 7L, 7L), .Label = c("White/Caucasian", 
"Other", "Multiple", "Black/African American", "Hispanic/Latinx", 
"American Indian or Alaskan Native", "No Selection", "Native Hawaiian or Pacific Islander", 
"Asian"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-140L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code would not work because R would not be able to find the variables in your data frame, e.g.

```
Predict_Table <- table(Student_Ethnicity, PreDAS_Ethnicity)
# Error in table(Student_Ethnicity, PreDAS_Ethnicity) : 
#   object 'Student_Ethnicity' not found
```

This does what you want, but the order of the categories is not alphabetical so you must have specified the order when you created the factors:

```
Predict_Table <- with(Predict_DAS, table(Student_Ethnicity, PreDAS_Ethnicity))
```